# In Swift, how can I unit test something dependent on a delay implemented with a private NSTimer?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, nstimer

I have a class that uses an `NSTimer` to buffer a change to one of its stored properties. I'm having trouble unit testing this class without having to expose the private properties and methods. Here is an illustrative version:

```
import CoreLocation

class BeaconActivity {
    private let reaction: BeaconActivity -> ()
    private var timer = NSTimer()
    private(set) var proximity = CLProximity.Unknown {
        didSet {
            self.reaction(self)
        }
    }

    init(reaction: BeaconActivity -> ()) {
        self.reaction = reaction
    }

    func startUpdate(proximity: CLProximity) {
        self.timer.invalidate()
        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: self, selector: "completeUpdate:", userInfo: proximity.rawValue, repeats: false)
    }

    dynamic private func completeUpdate(timer: NSTimer) {
        let rawValue = timer.userInfo as! Int
        self.proximity = CLProximity(rawValue: rawValue)!
    }
}
```

For example, how would I test that `reaction` that gets passed into the `init` runs when the `proximity` property is updated - without having to put a "sleep" in my test code?